# no kind "TZCronJob" is registered for version "cronjobber.hidde.co/v1alpha1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, k8s-cronjobber

#### Background

I am using TZCronJob to run cronjobs with timezones in Kubernetes. A sample `cronjob.yaml` might look like the following (as per the [cronjobber docs](https://github.com/hiddeco/cronjobber)). Note the timezone specified, the schedule, and `kind=TZCronJob`:

```
apiVersion: cronjobber.hidde.co/v1alpha1
kind: TZCronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "05 09 * * *"
  timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Nrmally, with any old cronjob in Kubernetes, you can run `kubectl create job test-job --from=tzcronjob/name_of_my_cronjob`, as per the [kubectl create cronjob docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-job-em-).

#### Error

However, when I try to run it with `kubectl create job test-job --from=tzcronjob/name_of_my_cronjob` (switching the from command to `--from=tzcronjob/`) I get:

> `error: from must be an existing cronjob: no kind "TZCronJob" is registered for version "cronjobber.hidde.co/v1alpha1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubectl/scheme/scheme.go:28"`

When I try to take a peek at https://kubernetes.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubectl/scheme/scheme.go:28 I get 404, not found.

This almost worked, but to no avail:

```
kubectl create job test-job-name-v1 --image=tzcronjob/name_of_image
```

How can I create a new one-off job from my chart definition?

Answer (score 1):

In [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/) there are mechanisms called [Hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#hooks).

Helm provides a hook mechanism to allow chart developers to intervene at certain points in a release’s life cycle. For example, you can use hooks to:

- Load a ConfigMap or Secret during install before any other charts are
  loaded
- Execute a Job to back up a database before installing a new chart,
  and then execute a second job after the upgrade in order to restore
  data
- Run a Job before deleting a release to gracefully take a service out
  of rotation before removing it.

Hooks work like regular templates, but they have special annotations that cause Helm to utilize them differently. In this section, we cover the basic usage pattern for hooks.

Hooks are declared as an annotation in the metadata section of a manifest:

```
apiVersion: ...
kind: ....
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
```

If the resources is a Job kind, Tiller will wait until the job successfully runs to completion. And if the job fails, the release will fail. This is a blocking operation, so the Helm client will pause while the Job is run.

**HOW TO WRITE HOOKS:**

Hooks are just Kubernetes manifest files with special annotations in the metadata section. Because they are template files, you can use all of the normal template features, including **reading .Values**, .**Release**, and **.Template**.

For example, this template, stored in templates/post-install-job.yaml, declares a job to be run on post-install:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{.Release.Name}}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{.Release.Service | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{.Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    helm.sh/chart: "{{.Chart.Name}}-{{.Chart.Version}}"
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{.Release.Name}}"
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{.Release.Service | quote }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{.Release.Name | quote }}
        helm.sh/chart: "{{.Chart.Name}}-{{.Chart.Version}}"
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: post-install-job
        image: "alpine:3.3"
        command: ["/bin/sleep","{{default "10" .Values.sleepyTime}}"]
```

What makes this template a hook is the annotation:

```
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
```

Comment: Thanks! hooks link is broken. I will see if I can get this to work for my use case and revisit.

Answer (score 0):

hava you register the custom resource TZCronJob? you can use `kubectl get crd` or `kubectl api-versions` to check.

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes natively supports CronJobs. you dont need to use custom resource definition or other third party objects. just update the yaml as below. It should work

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "05 09 * * *"
  timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

If you want to use timezone supported cronjob then follow the below steps to install cronjobber

```
# Install CustomResourceDefinition
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hiddeco/cronjobber/master/deploy/crd.yaml
# Setup service account and RBAC
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hiddeco/cronjobber/master/deploy/rbac.yaml
# Deploy Cronjobber (using the timezone db from the node)
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hiddeco/cronjobber/master/deploy/deploy.yaml
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I clarified my question. I have cronjobber installed already. I am interested in, "How can I create a new one-off job from my chart definition"?